# How to preserve current GET url in the browser while making POST request to server in Laravel-8 and InertiaJs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

I am using Inertia JS in Laravel 8, with following POST request to server. The problem is that the browser URL is also updated with POST request, which may be a expected behavior in some cases but I want to keep the actual GET request in the browser despite sending different types of requests to server using multiple Laravel routes.

```
this.$inertia.put(`/task/${task_id}`, {order, category_id});

this.$inertia.visit(`/task/${task_id}`, {
    method: 'put',
    data: {order, category_id},
    only: ['categories', 'msg'],
    replace: true,
    preserveState: true,
    preserveScroll: true,
});
```

Does anybody have the idea, how I can preserve existing GET URL in the browser while send POST requests to server using Inertia JS?

Comment: Did you find and solution?

Answer (score 3):

in your task controller, use `return Redirect::route('your_original_route');`

Comment: Example for your case it may look like something like this: `return Redirect::route('task', [$task])`

Answer (score 1):

you can try remove the
`replace: true`